# RewriteRule in htaccess is removing the SSL green lock

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

so I have this in the root .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ public/$1
```

my domain has SSL activated, but the following rule is disabling the https green lock, the URL is showing as https, but not the green lock.

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ public/$1`

I tried some other methods, but all lead to 500 Error.

Comment: If you say root do you mean the Document Root or the root of your APP and /public is the Document Root (this is the directory that is open if you do `https://example.com/`)

Comment: @Webdesigner I mean Document root, like this `https://example.com/`
not my app root.